# Jquery ajax: object in data object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, object

I need to pass an object within the data object but it's not working

I use the following function I found on this very site, very useful, to convert form data to JSON

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

and then I need to pass the object as a sub-object, but it's not working. Filters isn't even showing up in the query string parameters in the inspector

```
var filters = $('.filtersForm').serializeObject();

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {script:'search',page:page,filters:filters},
    success: function(data){
    }
});
```

[image]

See how "filters" is missing in the picture

Can someone please explain why I can't pass an object like that?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using this serializeObject function instead of JSON.stringify()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    script: 'search',
    page: page,
    filters: filters
  }),
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

1. Changed **type** from `GET` to `POST`.  This will allow you to send a request body.
2. Stringify your **data** parameter using the built-in JSON object to stringify your JS object to a JSON-formatted string.  (older browsers may not have this built-in object, in that case, add it using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js))
3. Set **contentType** to `application/json`.  This basically states that the request-body is of this type... which it is because we just stringified it to JSON.

Comment: Why would I need to stringify my initial object?

Comment: Serializing your JavaScript object to a JSON-formatted string is the best way to send your complex data to the server (part opinion).

Comment: Well but sending objects works as well, why can't I send an object within the object without stringyfiying ? I updated the question with a picture

Comment: Data sent over HTTP has to be flat (serialized).  JSON is often used because it lets you serialize complex objects.  You can then easily deserialize on the server.  If you 'stringify' your filters object, it should go over the wire with no problem.

Comment: Well that worked as to getting the parameter to show up, but now the object is always empty.. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specifiy your `filters` 
 
For example in try : 
`jsonfilter = JSON.stringify(filters);` 
If youre using MVC and ASP.Net you can try
In your HTTPWebMethode which have a jsonResult as Return you can try to specifiy parameters

```
  public JsonResult myPostMethode(string script,object page,List<object> filters){

    //make some usefull 
    var model = script;
    return(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```